# Abbreviation of institution in running text, full name in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I would like to use the abbreviation of an institution in the running text using `\citet{}`. But in the bibliography it should appear as the long name of the institution and the abbreviation. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you thinking of, say, `IMF` and `International Monetary Fund` as the abbreviated the full names of an institution? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, exactly! @Mico

Comment: If and how that is possible will to a large degree depend on the style you are using. Can you show us your current bibliography/citation setup in a small example document, please?

Comment: @moewe %******Start bibliography and citation******%
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\input{general/bibliography}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\makeatletter
\NAT@longnamesfalse
\makeatother
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\newcommand{\BBAA}{\&}% between authors in parenthetical cites and ref. list
\newcommand{\BBAB}{and}% between authors in in-text citation
\newcommand{\BAnd}{\&}% for ``Ed. \& Trans.'' in ref. list

%******End bibliography and citation******%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `natbib` package offers a method to create "aliases" for citation call-outs. This approach is available to users of the `apacite` package if you load it with the option `natbibapa`. Do look into natbib's `\defcitealias`, `\citetalias`, and `\citepalias` macros.

It is, of course, also possible to create macros -- called `\mycitet` and `\mycitep` below -- that output citation call-outs similar to `\citet` and `\citep` except that the abbreviated author name (defined via a `\defcitealias` macro mentioned earlier) is used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{imf2021oct,
   author = {{International Monetary Fund}},
   title  = {{World Economic Outlook}},
   year   = 2021,
   month  = oct,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\newcommand\mycitet[1]{\citetalias{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}
\newcommand\mycitep[1]{(\citetalias{#1}, \citeyear{#1})}
\defcitealias{imf2021oct}{IMF}
\bibliographystyle{apacite} % or some other suitable bibliography style

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citetalias{imf2021oct},
\citepalias{imf2021oct},
\mycitet{imf2021oct},
\mycitep{imf2021oct}

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```